# Issue with appending a line to a specific section of a configuration file using sed

Tags: sed

I'm using MacBook M1 Ventura 13.3.1 (a)

**Description:** I am encountering a problem while trying to append a line to a specific section of a configuration file using the `sed` command in my bash script. Here are the details:

**Problem Description:**
I have a configuration file named `Kernel.php` located in the `app/Http` directory relative to the root of my project. Within this file, there is an associative array with a key `'web'` that represents a configuration section. I want to append a new line inside this section, just before the closing `],` bracket.

Here's an example of what the section looks like before the modification:

```php
'web' => [
    // ... other lines
],
```

I want to add a line like this inside the section:

```php
    \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
```

**Attempts Made:**
I've tried using various `sed` commands to accomplish this task, but none of them seem to work as expected. For instance, I've tried commands like:

```bash
sed -i '/^'\''web'\'' => \[/,/\],/ { /],/ i\
    \\\App\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
}' app/Http/Kernel.php
```

**Expected Outcome:**
I expect the `sed` command to find the section starting with `'web' => [` and ending with `],`, then insert the new line `\App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,` just before the closing bracket `],`. The resulting section should look like this:

```php
'web' => [
    // ... other lines
    \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
],
```

**Actual Outcome:**
However, the `sed` command is not working as expected, and it does not make the desired changes to the file.

I need assistance in finding the correct `sed` command or alternative approach to accomplish this task. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on Mac (BSD) `sed`:

```bash
sed -i.bak -E "/'web' => \[/,/],/ { /(],)/s//    \\\App\\\Http\\\Middleware\\\HandleInertiaRequests::class,\n\1/; }" "app/Http/Kernel.php"

'web' => [
    // ... other lines
    \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
],
```

Comment: @anubhave Thank you. I've used your solution, but changed it a little bit and it worked ```sed -i.bak -E "/'web' => \[/,/],/ { /(],)/s//    \\\App\\\Http\\\Middleware\\\HandleInertiaRequests::class,\n\1/; }" "app/Http/Kernel.php"
``` so change please your answer accordingly and I will accept it. thanks again